# Exporting map with transparent background outside of polygon with QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I want to create a transparent output file (image) of the map with the outside border of the seven polygons being the overall border.

The rest of the background I want to be transparent (but within the polygon of the seven regions, the OSM layer is required).

I tried to follow other instructions but failed so far.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to create a dissolved copy of your polygon layer and use 'inverted polygons' under Layer properties -> Symbology. You can find the inverted polygons option in the drop-down menu at the top where you would normally select 'Single symbol', 'Categorized', or the like. If you then set the fill color to white, that should hide the OSM layer outside the polygons.